# Prediction methods to resolve differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

How resolved this difference equation used prediction methods? 
$$X' = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}1&-1&-2\\1&3&2\\1&-1&2\end{array}\right]X + \left[\begin{array}{c}t^{2}\\t+2\\2\end{array}\right]$$

Calculate eigenvalues and eigenvectors:
$$\lambda_{1} =  2 + 2i$$
$$\lambda_{2} = 2-2i$$
$$\lambda_{3} = 2$$

$$v_{1} =  (i,-i,1)$$
$$v_{2} = (-i,i,1)$$
$$v_{3} = (-1,-1,1)$$

So,

$$X_{b} = C_{1}\left(\begin{array}{c}i\\-i\\i\end{array}\right)e^{(2+2i)t} + C_{2} \left(\begin{array}{c}-i\\i\\1 \end{array}\right)e^{(2-2i)t} + C_{3} \left(\begin{array}{c}1\\-1\\ 1\end{array}\right)e^{2t}$$

How continue?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$\begin {matrix} \dfrac {e^{i x} + e^{-i x}}{2} = ? \text { and } \dfrac {e^{i x} - e^{-i x}}{2} = ? \end {matrix}$$

(in terms of what functions?)

Also, $$\begin {matrix} \dfrac {e^{x} + e^{-x}}{2} = ? \text { and } \dfrac {e^{x} - e^{-x}}{2} = ? \end {matrix}$$

(in terms of what other functions?)

Comment: $$ \frac{e^{x} + e^{-x}}{2} =  \cosh{x} $$
$$ \frac{e^{x} - e^{-x}}{2} = \sinh{x} $$   $$ \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2} =  \cos{x} $$
$$ \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i} = \sin{x} $$ but, what next?